# Firebase Database RULES, problems in getting data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Hi Guys, I have some problem with Firebase Database Rules.
I'm putting this code in my rules section:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "pizzerie": {
      "$casualWord" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And I have a databased structured in this way:**

```
{
  "pizzerie" : {
    "pizzeriaDaLuigi" : {
  "Info" : {
    "apertiPranzo" : false,
    "apertoLunedi" : true,
    "apertoMartedi" : false,
    "colore" : "#38dce0",
    "indirizzo" : "Caserta",
    "indirizzoCompleto" : "Via Giacomo Puccini, Macerata Campania, 81047, Caserta",
    "nome" : "I Masanielli",
    "senzaGlutine" : true,
    "spazioEsterno" : true,
    "telefono" : "3202777037"
  },
  "Prenotazioni" : {
    "pizzeriaDaLuigi001" : {
      "anno" : 2018,
      "giorno" : 21,
      "mese" : 5,
      "minuto" : 30,
      "ora" : 21,
      "persone" : 8
    }
  }
}
```

**I'm accessing to those information with this javascript code:**

```
database.ref('pizzerie').once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

        console.log(child.child('Info/colore').val());
});
}
```

**But nothing is being returned, why ?**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**Query:**

```
database.ref('pizzerie').once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
         var childData = child.val();

         console.log(childData.Info.colore);
      });
})
```

**Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "pizzerie": {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear it sems not working. The part of the  database.ref... is not entered completely

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: The database doesn't allow access to the directory "pizzerie"

Comment: Look dear, I've updated the question. I want them to be able to read from "Info" but not from "Prenotazioni"